# correlate data-frame columns with last activity

Tags: r, for-loop

am at a fix here i have some exam data with

```
Student ID, question ID, Option ID, activity
00011        55525        7896       save
00011        55525        7896       save
00011        55526        7898      save
00011        55526        7898       save
00011        55527        7897       save
00012        55527        7897       save
00012        55528        7898       save
00012        55528        7898       save
00013        55529        7899       save
00013        55529        7899       save
00013        55522        7892       save
00012        55522        7892       save
00013        55522        7892       save
```

i want to edit the data according to the roll num, qid, sid means the final output should be roll num matching the qid matching the sid according to the last save activity.  for that i removed count but my loop isn't giving me the correct matches can u help with the code thanks.

```
library(plyr)
Check<-count(check5,c('student id','Question ID','Option.ID','Activity'))

Check$student id<-as.numeric(as.character(Check$student id))
Roll <- Check[,'student id']

Check$Question ID<-as.numeric(as.character(Check$Question ID))
QID <- Check[,'Question ID']

SID <- Check[,'Option.ID']

num1 <- Check[,'freq']

cdat <- matrix(, nrow =480, ncol = 3)
```

expected output -->

```
Student ID, question ID, Option ID
     00011        55525        7896   
     00011        55526        7898   
     00011        55527        7897
     00013        55529        7899 
     00013        55522        7892 
     00012        55528        7898
```

sid matches qid matching oid according to corresponding last save for it.
 i do not want the same matching SID to be repeated twice i want only all matching values to be displayed only once.

Comment: Can you show the expected output based on the input data you showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
# data replication
df <- data.frame(S.ID = c("00011","00011","00011","00011","00011","00012","00012","00012","00013","00013","00013","00012","00013"),
                 Q.ID = c(55525,55525,55526,55526,55527,55527,55528,55528,55529,55529,55522,55522,55522),
                 O.ID = c(7896,7896,7898,7898,7897,7897,7898,7898,7899,7899,7892,7892,7892),
                 activity = rep("save", 13), stringsAsFactors = F)

# Modified function
aggregate(S.ID ~ O.ID + Q.ID, data = df, tail, n = 1)

  O.ID  Q.ID  S.ID
1 7892 55522 00013
2 7896 55525 00011
3 7898 55526 00011
4 7897 55527 00012
5 7898 55528 00012
6 7899 55529 00013
```

Comment: Is the output correct? If save is the only value in activity column, then just use `unique(df)`. I showed the data replication and result to make sure if this is the result you want to make.

Comment: No @zyurnaidi i did changes in my loop but values are repeated, iwant the output just as my expected output

Comment: Oh, sorry. NOW I get it. So the unique values to be matched on is Q.ID and O.ID combination, while S.ID would depend on the latest save. Correct?

Comment: yes yes i want only the unique combination with the last save